# Take the sqlplus's result and put into a variable on script .bat

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I'm not know the batch structure and forgive me if this questions is trivals.
I have my query and i would like to execute them into a script with sqlplus command. After that, when my sqlplus command give me a result, i would like to save the record in a variable and the last step is create a mail with mailto command and send it to my contact.

my script is these:

ScriptFather.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET i=0
FOR /f  %%b IN ('C:\Users\samuele.nava\Desktop\idlock.bat') DO (set var!i!=%%b)
echo var0: !var0!
pause
```

ScriptSon.bat

```
sqlplus user/pwd@host:port/sid @C:\...\Query.sql
```

Query.sql

```
select id_richiesta,id_ric_tipo,id_lock,ts_ins,ts_ultimo_aggiornamento,codice_op_don,codice_op_rec,id_richiesta_stati,data_cut_over_richiesta,data_cut_over_effettiva from richieste where id_lock is not null and ts_ultimo_aggiornamento=(sysdate) order by ts_ultimo_aggiornamento desc;
```

Sorry at all if these problem is common but i don't know how to resolve this question.

Regard and rock'n'roll

Comment: Your for command is using the variable `%%m` but you are trying to assign the variable `%%b`.  Also you are trying to use delayed expansion with the `var!i!` variable but you have not enabled delayed expansion with the `SETLOCAL` command.

Comment: StackOverFlow works a little different then a regular Q&A forum. Don't put code edits in a comment. Edit your question with your updated code and delete your comment.

Comment: @Squashman ty...i'm update to code in my question. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think condition `ts_ultimo_aggiornamento=(sysdate)` returns any result. Most likely you are looking for `ts_ultimo_aggiornamento=TRUNC(sysdate)`

Comment: Do you like to send a mail for each single line or one mail with all records?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mayor challenge is to format the sqlplus output. Have a look at this document [Formatting SQL*Plus Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm)

Once you did this I would propose to spool result into a file and mail it, for example using SendSMTP which you can download from http://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/utilitiesprogs/sendsmtp.htm

```
sqlplus -s user/pwd@host:port/sid @Query.sql > %TEMP%\Query_output.txt

SendSMTP.exe /HOST mailhost /FROM "Samuele@domain.net" /TO "Samuele@domain.net" /SUBJECT "Notification from Database" /BODYFILE %TEMP%\Query_output.txt
```

Note the `-s` switch which suppresses the sqlplus banner.

Comment: It's run but i'm not very satisfied. iId like to control the row input, in fact if there is "no row selected" in the record output, my script mustn't send a e-mail. With your solution how can i control this thing?
ty a lot

Comment: My proposal is to download gnuwin32 from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/. Then you could use `grep "no row selected"` in order to find out whether you got any result. Or change your entire script to **VB Script** (or PowerShell nowadays), there you have much more functions.